# How to run a method from Sequel extension as SQL function

Tags: ruby, sequel, sql-function

How can I define a Ruby method in a custom Sequel extension stored in `/lib/sequel/extensions/`, that would be responsible for creating an SQL function right after the extension was loaded. I don't want to have a method definition in a database migration file.

I can do this:

```
Sequel.migration do
  change do
    create_table :some_table do
      primary_key :id
      String :uuid, null: false, default: Sequel.function(:uuid_generate_v4), unique: true
    end
  end
end
```

And I know `uuid_generate_v4` is stored in the `uuid-ossp` extension, so all I have to do to be able to call this function, is to add the extension to my codebase.

Unfortunately, I don't know how. What would be the cleanest way to define such function and make it callable without manually calling a Ruby method first?

My extension file:

```
module Sequel
  module Extensions
    module StringGenerator
      def some_ruby_method
        DB.create_function('sql_function_name', 'SELECT 1', :returns=>:integer)
      end
    end

    Sequel::Database.register_extension(
      :string_generator,
      Sequel::Extensions::StringGenerator
    )
  end
end
```

`sql_function` is not reachable from code without calling `some_ruby_method` manually.

How is `uuid_generate_v4` executable right after being added as an extension and what I need to do for the same outcome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be confusing Sequel extensions and PostgreSQL extensions.  `uuid-ossp` is a PostgreSQL extension.

Having a Sequel extension create a database function when loaded is probably a bad idea, but it is possible.

`Sequel::Database.register_extension` can accept a block instead of a module, and the block is called with the `Sequel::Database` instance that loads the extension.

Comment: Thank you, seems like all of the points you brought up make sense. I'll play around with the blocks and will read a bit more on the extensions subject